# Displaying certain items in lists

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a set of questions with their respective topics and then I want to ask the user which questions they want to study. Depending on their response I then want to then display just those questions. (For example if they respond with "maths" I want all the questions with the topic "maths" to be displayed)

so far I have this code;

```
from collections import *

question = []
topic = []

t = 4

while t > 0:
    x = input("what is your question?")
    y = input("what is the topic?")
    question.append(x)
    topic.append(y)
    data = defaultdict(list)
    for topic, question in zip(topic, question):
        data[topic].append(question)

    t -= 1

z = input("what topic would you like to study?")
print(data[z])
```

which works fine on the first iteration however when i enter the values in the second iteration this error occurs;

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sam/PycharmProjects/ComputingProject/lists.py", line 11, in 
    question.append(x)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

why does it not work the second time around?

Comment: Please refrain from changing the nature of your question after there have been answers posted. Simple follow-up questions can be asked in the comments; more complicated reworks would be better served by asking a new question.

Comment: @glibdud noted. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zip` creates pairs. In your case, you should probably use a dict, mapping from topic to a list of questions.

```
 data = defaultdict(list)
 for topic, question in zip(topics, questions):
     data[topic].append(question)
```

note: `defaultdict` is a variation of `dict` (which you should study first), to avoid checking if a topic already exists in the dict

Comment: I guess it's worth to mention that `dict` and `defaultdict(list)` are two different types

Comment: @blue_note hi, thank you for the help but I have now ran into another problem. I have altered the question above ^. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you are using `question` as variable in you loop, so it overwrites the list `question=[]` you have created. same for topic. Change the list names to `question_list, topic_list` or something